# Not able to include pthread.h in Windows

Tags: c, eclipse, multithreading, posix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get C’s pthread.h to compile in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150938/can-i-get-cs-pthread-h-to-compile-in-windows)

I am using eclipse on Windows 7.I am trying multi threaded programming in C.But I am not able to include pthread.h.It says No such file or directory.It worked on another Windows 7 machine but does not seem to work on this one.Please help me out.

Comment: pthread is a unix library, so if it worked on another windows installation, it must have been because you used a port of the library for windows.

Comment: The P in Pthread stands for POSIX, which is a standard used on most UNIX or UNIX-like operating systems (like Linux and OSX). It's _not_ available for Windows. See instead a Windows-specific reference of [threads and processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

pthreads, also known as POSIX threads, are a facility of POSIX-conformant operating systems (usually Unix-like systems, such as Linux and Mac OS X.) Windows does not have it. You will need to install a Windows port of pthreads. You can get it here: http://sources.redhat.com/pthreads-win32

Comment: I tried this but it does not work

Comment: @SB26 You will probably need to tell your compiler where to find the header files as well as the library files. How you do that depends on your compiler.

Comment: I am using MinGW and the header files are in that folder.I extracted the header files related to POSIX in that particular folder.