# pthread.h does not exist

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was looking at online multithreading tutorials in c++ when I found that `#include <pthread.h>` causes an error. The error is:

> fatal error: No such file or directory

Please help me fix what is wrong. Also remember that I am a noob, so please keep the explanations simple.

Comment: That header isn't part of standard C++. You need to get the library.

Comment: Oh. Where do I download it?

Comment: From whatever website they have? I don't use it.

Comment: It sounds like you're using a Unix book, are you using a Unix compiler or are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks on windows xp. I'm using the GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get C's pthread.h to compile in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150938/can-i-get-cs-pthread-h-to-compile-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Use -Ipath,where your pthread.h located