# unable to compile C files (MEX) in matlab (Windows) using GNU GCC

Tags: c, matlab, gcc, gnu, mex

I am trying to compile native linux c files on windows using GNU GCC compilers. For the installation purpose, I have followed the steps mentioned by Faheem in the following link :

[Using GCC(minGW) as Matlab's MEX compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552580/using-gccmingw-as-matlabs-mex-compiler)

the example given there compiled successfully. but when i am trying to compile a file using thread functions, the following error is being thrown:

**fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory 
 #include  
                     ^ 
compilation terminated.**

I have installed all the components from MinGW installer related to GNU C compiler bu still the error persists. Can any one suggest a way to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pthread.h` is a POSIX library for threading which can't be found on your system as you're using Windows.  You'll need to get them here: https://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/.  Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150938/can-i-get-cs-pthread-h-to-compile-in-windows

Comment: did you check the presence [and if not there, copying] `pthread.h` into `MinGW/include` or similar path?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. And yes Mr. Sourav, I tried doing that. But then it was asking for more header files and more missing functions. There was no end to that.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Rayryeng, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [TDM-GCC "Quircks" page](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/quirks), TDM-GCC includes a pthreads emulation layer for Microsoft Windows systems, called "winpthreads", and a recent toolchain you should have `x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\pthread.h` in the TDM install path.  So, I don't know what is wrong with Faheem's instructions, but you should have no trouble including pthread.h if MATLAB is configured correctly.

What is not stated on the TDM Quircks page is that TDM uses Winpthreads from the MinGW-w64 project.  From the current README installed with TDM:

> "Winpthreads" is one of the libraries distributed by the MinGW-w64 project, and
>   it allows GCC to be compiled with full pthreads compatibility, which is
>   necessary to enable std::thread and other threading related functions in the
>   C++ runtime.

As it states, Pthreads is part of the MinGW-w64 project and you can also get it with MinGW-w64 if you pick a pthreads enabled toolchain.  For MinGW-w64, I do the following to set it up ([see here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28490382/2778484)):

1. Grab the [latest revision for w64 from Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.2/threads-posix/seh/) (or use [the installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download) to choose the toolchain you want, picking a pthread version).
2. Extract it so that you have a path to the compiler like `C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-4.9.2-release-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev1\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`.  **There is no need for MSYS, cygwin, or any other environment if you plan on compiling in MATLAB with `mex`**.
3. Set it up with a custom mexopts.bat or using the new xml configuration system. On my GitHub repo, I have C++ configurations for MinGW-w64 in both file types: [mingw_mexopts.bat](https://github.com/chappjc/MATLAB/blob/master/MinGW/mingw_mexopts.bat) and [mex_C++_mingw-w64.xml](https://github.com/chappjc/MATLAB/blob/master/MinGW/mex_C%2B%2B_mingw-w64.xml).  For example, using the xml file to set up C++ MEX file compilation:

   ```
   mex -setup:C:\Users\Jon\Documents\MATLAB\mex_C++_mingw-w64.xml C++
   ```

   If needed, set up the C compiler in a similar manner by modifying the config files.

I posted a more detailed version of the above instructions in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28490382/2778484) to [the canonical question on the MinGW-with-MATLAB topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8552580/2778484).