# error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I am trying to build a project using Qt creator tool in windows but when I built it , I got this error: 
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory.

So do I have to download this library? but i did not find it

I am using Qt in order to open aa tool called netanim used for NS3 tool

If any one can help me in this issue, I would be appreciative.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: If you're using Qt, why not just use [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html)?

Comment: It is answered on the link below:
[The answer is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150938/can-i-get-unixs-pthread-h-to-compile-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

On most unix systems there should be a /usr/include/pthread.h if you have the developer tools. On windows, you would need some sort of 'windows pthread emulation library'