# How to tell CMake where to find pthread.h on Windows

Tags: cmake-gui

EDIT: NEVERMIND - I had already successfully fixed this problem by putting a copy of the header where the compiler would find it.  However, other build errors in cmake-gui kept referring me to the old error log file with the old build error, making me falsely believe I had not solved the problem.

I will close this question once the seven day bounty period is expired.

---

I am attempting to create a Windows port of a Linux library that uses pthreads via pthreads-win32, but I am having issues telling CMAKE where to locate pthreads.h.  Does anyone know how to direct CMAKE to look to a specific location for pthreads.h?  And also for the library file?

Alternately, is there some sort of magical global include directory I could use?

Comment: i don't know whether it will  work. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html

Answer (score 1):

For example , in CMakeLists.txt , you can  use   [INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) to include the path　.

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES([AFTER|BEFORE] [SYSTEM] dir1 dir2 ...)
```

and you can  add the `link path` of `pthread.h` with this  when you want to link the library :

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES(directory1 directory2 ...)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(target library1<debug | optimized> library2...)
```

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37598241/6229548) , it say that you can link with `libwinpthread.a`