# How can I let CMake find an external package?

Tags: cmake, pthreads, grpc, pthreads-win32

I tried to build [Qv2ray](https://github.com/Qv2ray/Qv2ray) with CMake and Visual Studio on Windows and got the error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/backend.cmake:9 (message):
  gRPC Not Found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:257 (include)
```

Check backend.cmake:

```
find_program(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN grpc_cpp_plugin)

find_package(gRPC CONFIG QUIET)

# Debian, for example, cannot find gRPC in a proper way.
# This is used as a fallback searching method
if(NOT gRPC_FOUND)
    if(WIN32)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "gRPC Not Found")
    else()
    ......
```

I've built gRPC and installed it to C:\gRPC. How can I let CMake find it?
If I add

```
SET(gRPC_DIR "C:/gRPC/lib/cmake/grpc")
```

before `find_package`, I got this error:

```
-- Could NOT find absl (missing: absl_DIR)
CMake Error at cmake/backend.cmake:9 (message):
  gRPC Not Found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:257 (include)
```

If I also set absl_DIR, I got another error:

```
    Performing C SOURCE FILE Test UV_LINT_NO_UNUSED_PARAMETER failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-ixqh17

Run Build Command(s):C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_cc832 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_cc832.dir\src.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_cc832.dir/src.c.obj 
"C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"  /nologo -DUV_LINT_NO_UNUSED_PARAMETER  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1   -Wno-unused-parameter /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_cc832.dir\src.c.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_cc832.dir\ /FS -c C:\v2ray\qv2ray\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-ixqh17\src.c
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unused-parameter'

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.



Source file was:
int main(void) { return 0; }

Performing C SOURCE FILE Test UV_LINT_STRICT_PROTOTYPES failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-ckl2px

Run Build Command(s):C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_54f78 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_54f78.dir\src.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_54f78.dir/src.c.obj 
"C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"  /nologo -DUV_LINT_STRICT_PROTOTYPES  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1   -Wstrict-prototypes /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_54f78.dir\src.c.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_54f78.dir\ /FS -c C:\v2ray\qv2ray\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-ckl2px\src.c
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wstrict-prototypes'

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.



Source file was:
int main(void) { return 0; }

Performing C SOURCE FILE Test UV_LINT_EXTRA failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-oz29mu

Run Build Command(s):C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_c075b && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_c075b.dir\src.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_c075b.dir/src.c.obj 
"C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"  /nologo -DUV_LINT_EXTRA  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1   -Wextra /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_c075b.dir\src.c.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_c075b.dir\ /FS -c C:\v2ray\qv2ray\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-oz29mu\src.c
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wextra'

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.



Source file was:
int main(void) { return 0; }

Performing C SOURCE FILE Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-d5iufb

Run Build Command(s):C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_b1e72 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_b1e72.dir\src.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1e72.dir/src.c.obj 
"C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"  /nologo -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_b1e72.dir\src.c.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_b1e72.dir\ /FS -c C:\v2ray\qv2ray\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-d5iufb\src.c
C:\v2ray\qv2ray\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-d5iufb\src.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.



Source file was:
#include <pthread.h>

static void* test_func(void* data)
{
  return data;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
  pthread_detach(thread);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}


Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-cyjamz

Run Build Command(s):C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_863f5 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_863f5.dir\CheckFunctionExists.c.obj

[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_863f5.exe

FAILED: cmTC_863f5.exe 

cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_863f5.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- "C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe" /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_863f5.dir\CheckFunctionExists.c.obj  /out:cmTC_863f5.exe /implib:cmTC_863f5.lib /pdb:cmTC_863f5.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  pthreads.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_863f5.dir\CheckFunctionExists.c.obj /out:cmTC_863f5.exe /implib:cmTC_863f5.lib /pdb:cmTC_863f5.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console pthreads.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_863f5.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_863f5.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'pthreads.lib'


ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.




Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthread failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-ymkre8

Run Build Command(s):C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_2ac36 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_2ac36.dir\CheckFunctionExists.c.obj

[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_2ac36.exe

FAILED: cmTC_2ac36.exe 

cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_2ac36.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- "C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe" /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_2ac36.dir\CheckFunctionExists.c.obj  /out:cmTC_2ac36.exe /implib:cmTC_2ac36.lib /pdb:cmTC_2ac36.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  pthread.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_2ac36.dir\CheckFunctionExists.c.obj /out:cmTC_2ac36.exe /implib:cmTC_2ac36.lib /pdb:cmTC_2ac36.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console pthread.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_2ac36.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_2ac36.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'pthread.lib'


ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

**I downloaded pthread-win32, copied pthreadVC2.lib to pthread.lib and added the following line to CMakeLists.txt,**

```
    set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "/LIBPATH:\"C:\\pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release\\Pre-built.2\\lib\\x64\\\"")

then rebuilt but still got the error:

Performing C SOURCE FILE Test UV_LINT_NO_UNUSED_PARAMETER failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-wqbrhl

Run Build Command(s):C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_7b6af && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_7b6af.dir\src.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_7b6af.dir/src.c.obj 
"C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"  /nologo -DUV_LINT_NO_UNUSED_PARAMETER  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1   -Wno-unused-parameter /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_7b6af.dir\src.c.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_7b6af.dir\ /FS -c C:\v2ray\qv2ray\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wqbrhl\src.c
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unused-parameter'

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.



Source file was:
int main(void) { return 0; }

Performing C SOURCE FILE Test UV_LINT_STRICT_PROTOTYPES failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-e8xc9e

Run Build Command(s):C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_f19a7 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_f19a7.dir\src.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_f19a7.dir/src.c.obj 
"C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"  /nologo -DUV_LINT_STRICT_PROTOTYPES  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1   -Wstrict-prototypes /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_f19a7.dir\src.c.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_f19a7.dir\ /FS -c C:\v2ray\qv2ray\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e8xc9e\src.c
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wstrict-prototypes'

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.



Source file was:
int main(void) { return 0; }

Performing C SOURCE FILE Test UV_LINT_EXTRA failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-0dci1s

Run Build Command(s):C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_33837 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_33837.dir\src.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_33837.dir/src.c.obj 
"C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"  /nologo -DUV_LINT_EXTRA  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1   -Wextra /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_33837.dir\src.c.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_33837.dir\ /FS -c C:\v2ray\qv2ray\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-0dci1s\src.c
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wextra'

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.



Source file was:
int main(void) { return 0; }

Performing C SOURCE FILE Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-fxbu04

Run Build Command(s):C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_79d11 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_79d11.dir\src.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_79d11.dir/src.c.obj 
"C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"  /nologo -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_79d11.dir\src.c.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_79d11.dir\ /FS -c C:\v2ray\qv2ray\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-fxbu04\src.c
C:\v2ray\qv2ray\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-fxbu04\src.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.



Source file was:
#include <pthread.h>

static void* test_func(void* data)
{
  return data;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
  pthread_detach(thread);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}


Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-nnzju3

Run Build Command(s):C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_1b1f1 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_1b1f1.dir\CheckFunctionExists.c.obj

[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_1b1f1.exe

FAILED: cmTC_1b1f1.exe 

cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_1b1f1.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- "C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe" /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_1b1f1.dir\CheckFunctionExists.c.obj  /out:cmTC_1b1f1.exe /implib:cmTC_1b1f1.lib /pdb:cmTC_1b1f1.pdb /version:0.0 /LIBPATH:"C:\pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release\Pre-built.2\lib\x64\"  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  pthreads.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
LINK: command "C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_1b1f1.dir\CheckFunctionExists.c.obj /out:cmTC_1b1f1.exe /implib:cmTC_1b1f1.lib /pdb:cmTC_1b1f1.pdb /version:0.0 /LIBPATH:C:\pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release\Pre-built.2\lib\x64"  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  pthreads.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib  /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:cmTC_1b1f1.exe.manifest" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
CheckFunctionExists.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pthread_create referenced in function main


cmTC_1b1f1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals


ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.




Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthread failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-4uqkdk

Run Build Command(s):C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_12c03 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_12c03.dir\CheckFunctionExists.c.obj

[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_12c03.exe

FAILED: cmTC_12c03.exe 

cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_12c03.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- "C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe" /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_12c03.dir\CheckFunctionExists.c.obj  /out:cmTC_12c03.exe /implib:cmTC_12c03.lib /pdb:cmTC_12c03.pdb /version:0.0 /LIBPATH:"C:\pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release\Pre-built.2\lib\x64\"  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  pthread.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
LINK: command "C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_12c03.dir\CheckFunctionExists.c.obj /out:cmTC_12c03.exe /implib:cmTC_12c03.lib /pdb:cmTC_12c03.pdb /version:0.0 /LIBPATH:C:\pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release\Pre-built.2\lib\x64"  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  pthread.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib  /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:cmTC_12c03.exe.manifest" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
CheckFunctionExists.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pthread_create referenced in function main


cmTC_12c03.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals


ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The error messages in cmake build window are:

```
-- Found CURL: C:\curl-7.87.0-win64-mingw\lib (found version "7.87.0")
-- Found Protobuf: C:\protobuf-21.12\lib (found version "3.21.12")
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
CMake Error at cmake/backend.cmake:16 (message):
  gRPC Not Found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:257 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/v2ray/qv2ray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Probably, absl_DIR and pthread are both required by gRPC. But I don't think this is the correct way to let CMake find gRPC since I can run the executables in C:\gRPC\bin\ without problem so gRPC should be able to find the components it depends automatically. What is the correct way to let CMake find gRPC?

Comment: "But I don't think this is the correct way to let CMake find gRPC since I can run the executables in C:\gRPC\bin\ without problem" - No, your implications are wrong. Ability to run the executable has nothing common with being able to find a package with `find_package`. Setting `absl_DIR` is a proper way for make `find_package(absl)` to work. Setting `gRPC_DIR` is a proper way for make `find_package(gRPC)` to work. As for `pthread.lib` error, without the code of your project and without more detailed error message we can only guess why you get it.

Comment: Pssibly related: [Error : LNK1104 cannot open file 'pthread.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53752689/11107541)

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've updated the question with more error information.

Comment: "If I also set absl_DIR, I got another error ..." - The following is not the error in the **output** but a content of `CMakeError.log` file. Not sure why do you post it here: this file is full of error messages about compilation attempts with different parameters. Almost any project, except "hello world", performs such attempts for detect features of the target platform. If you want more detailed message about why gRPC is treated as not found on your system, then remove `QUIET` keyword in `find_package(gRPC)` call.

Comment: `cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unused-parameter'` looks like an attempt was made to add a gcc compiler option for MSVC. Perhaps the lib was built for mingw and is expected to be used with the gcc version that comes with it? It may be possible to fix this by installing a different version of the lib that's meant for gcc, but I'm not familiar enough with the lib to tell, so that's something for you to research...