# I am unable to build using cmake error 1083

Tags: cmake-gui

I've tried to search this problem and can't see any exactly related to my issue using windows 10 64bit and when I configure/generate in cmake for build azerothcore I get only one following error:

```
F:\WoWP\Acore\Build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1): fatal
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or
directory [F:\WoWP\Acore\Build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_e7615.vcxproj]
```

Comment: Sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150938/can-i-get-unixs-pthread-h-to-compile-in-windows

Comment: Seems like you missed the `include_directory` to the `pthread.h`. @Ddraig I could check  your `CMakeLists.txt` , in case you provide it in this issue.